# Spring MVC Ajax Date Field, The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

We have following error:

```
The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

and code

```
<%@page language="Java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(function() {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker()
    });

    $('.addbutton').click(function() {   
        var val = $('#objectForm').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url : 'object-add',
            type: 'POST',
            data : val,
            success : function(event) {
                alert('object successfully added!');
            },
        });        
    });
});
</script>

<div class="menu">
    <button class="addbutton" value="AddButton">AddButton</button>
</div>

<form:form modelAttribute="objectAttribute" id="objectForm">
        <h3>Object Details</h3>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="objectId">Object ID</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="objectId"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="brand">Brand</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="brand"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="year">Year</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="year" class="datepicker"/></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</form:form>
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "object-add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addObject(ModelMap model,
        @ModelAttribute("objectAttribute") Object object) {

    objectService.insert(object);

    return "index";
}
```

Entity - Year Field

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "YEAR", length = 7)
public Date getYear() {
    return this.year;
}

public void setYear(Date year) {
    this.year = year;
}
```

If there is no year field (in webpage form), everything is fine and object stored in the database.
I don't know how to deal with the date.

As you can see there is a plugin jquery UI with the set format 'dateFormat: "yy-M-dd"'.

In addition, I am using Oracle database

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I did like that and it works well

Entity

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yy-mm-dd") <-- set date format
@Column(name = "YEAR", length = 7)
public Date getYear() {
    return this.year;
}
```

and jQuery UI config

```
'dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
```